# react-leaflet polygon eventHandler not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Simple question, I am dynamically rendering `Polygons` using `react-leaflet`.

The polygons appear as expected. However, whatever i attach to `eventHandlers` does not work.

```
  const highlightFeature = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    let layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
      color: "black",
      fillColor: "black"
    });
  };

let indents = [];
  lightRailStop.features.map((feature, index) => {
    indents.push(
      <Polygon
        positions={feature.geometry.coordinates}
        clickable={true}
        color={"red"}
        stroke={false}
        fillOpacity={0.45}

        // This is not working!
        eventHandlers={{
          mouseover: highlightFeature,
          click: () => {
            console.log("marker clicked");
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  });
```

Why is this so, and how do i fix it?

Full fiddle:
https://codesandbox.io/s/scratchpad-without-geojson-b8jsp5

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox you posted is using `react-leaflet` version 2.  Version 2 handles events differently.  A simple `onClick` prop will work.  For the other handlers, you can use `onMouseEnter` or `onMouseOut`:

```js
  <Polygon
      key={index}
      positions={feature.geometry.coordinates}
      onClick={() => console.log("this works")}
      onMouseenter={highlightFeature}
      onMouseut={(e) => console.log(e)}
    />
```

### [Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scratchpad-without-geojson-forked-2y83rx?file=/src/App.js:2285-2602)

I do recommend updating to react-leaflet v3 though.